# ComboBox to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, textbox

I'm trying to do this: when the user changes the value in the `ComboBox`, the `TextBox` have to display the selection.

These are my `ComboBoxItems`:

```
<ComboBoxItem>Select Filter</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem>by name</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem>by age</ComboBoxItem>
```

The Method:

```
private void filterCbx_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{                    
    String selection = this.filterCbx.SelectedValue.ToString();
    filterTxt.Text = selection;
}
```

The result:

> System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Select a Filter

The same happens when I change the selected `ComboBoxItem`:

> System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: by name
>
> System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: by age

how I can get rid of the `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem:` part?

Answer (score 2):

Try with *xaml* only

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue.Content, ElementName=filterCbx}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that SelectedValue is ComboBoxItem, so first you need to cast it, and then take it's content:

```
String selection = string.Empty;
var selectedItem = this.filterCbx.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem;
if (selectedItem != null)
 selection = selectedItem.Content.ToString();
```